# How to use np.select but with multiples conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this kind of dataframe (only have 1.0 or 2.0) :

| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| 2.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I would like to create a new column, based on the row values of the other three columns, in pseudo code this would give :

if column_1 = 1.0 or column_2 = 1.0 or column_3 = 1.0, return 1.0 in df['column_4']

if column_1 and column_2 = 1.0 or column_1 and column_3 = 1.0 or column_2 and column_3 = 1.0, return 2.0 in df['column_4]

if column_1 and column_2 and column_3 = 1.0, return 3.0 in df['column_4']

else 0.0

I can't put it in code, this is my attempt for now :

```
sum_1 = df.loc[(df.column_1 == 1.0) | (df.column_2 == 1.0) | (df.column_3 == 1.0)]
sum_2 = df.loc[((df.column_1 == 1.0) & (df.column_2 == 1.0)) | ((df.column_1 == 1.0) & (df.column_3 == 1.0)) | (df.column_2 == 1.0) & (df.column_3 == 1.0)]
sum_3 = df.loc[(df.column_1 == 1.0) & (df.column_3 == 1.0) & (df.column_2 == 1.0)]


df['column_4'] = np.select([sum_1, sum_2, sum_3], [1.0, 2.0 , 3.0], default=0.0)
```

But i have an ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Sorry if my question is an easy thing and txh for any help!

Comment: isn't just a sum? in that cas it is `df["column_4"] = df.sum(axis = 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `loc` part in your `sum_x` variable and `np.select` check condition in sequence, so you need to put stricter condition to front

```py
sum_1 = (df.column_1 == 1.0) | (df.column_2 == 1.0) | (df.column_3 == 1.0)
sum_2 = ((df.column_1 == 1.0) & (df.column_2 == 1.0)) | ((df.column_1 == 1.0) & (df.column_3 == 1.0)) | (df.column_2 == 1.0) & (df.column_3 == 1.0)
sum_3 = (df.column_1 == 1.0) & (df.column_3 == 1.0) & (df.column_2 == 1.0)

df['column_4'] = np.select([sum_3, sum_2, sum_1], [3.0, 2.0, 1.0], default=0.0)
```

```
print(df)

   column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4
0       1.0       2.0       2.0       1.0
1       1.0       1.0       2.0       2.0
2       2.0       1.0       1.0       2.0
```

Or you can use `sum` on columns

```py
df['column_4'] = df.eq(1).sum(axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

   column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4
0       1.0       2.0       2.0       1.0
1       1.0       1.0       2.0       2.0
2       2.0       1.0       1.0       2.0
```

Comment: @onyambu Thank you for leaving a comment. Didn't notice OP edited his data and I notice that `np.select` has error and fix it.

Comment: @onyambu Thank you, when I leave the comment, I just prepare to re-run the code with new data thus didn't fix it. Didn't expect you come back so quickly :).

Comment: Hahaha. Yeah. Already upvoted